# Joining/ querying large tables

Tags: sql

**[Aim]**
We would like to look up if an event already exists in table A and if so how many times. This count() should then be joined in a single query comprising of all of table B events and the count of table A occurences.

**[Context]**
'Table A' has ~4 million rows with following structure: 
`| unique_id | date |`
'Table B' has ~1 million rows with following structure: `| unique_id | date | cost |`
'unique_id' is the system-wide id that we can use to do "joins"

**[Expected outcomes]**
Have an output as follows:

```
b.unique_id | b.date | 'count of A events, if any' | b.cost
```

**[Problem]**
- How to structure this query in that it runs as fast as possible? A view? A query? Something else?

Thanks!

Comment: you need to use index for it!!!..it will help :)

Comment: Also which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? In general the first step in tuning is to look at the execution plan.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to do several different things (determine if a record exists, get a count, get related records...).  Can you give an example of what the output should look like?

Comment: If the ids are unique, won't the counts always be 1?

Comment: thanks for the replies. 
DBMS = MySQL 5.6
Output example: 
unique_id | count
123           | 10
222           | 2

The ids themselves are unique in the database. But in both table a and b they are logging events. In other words, unique_id=1, can have multiple events in either table

Answer (score 1):

The query that you seem to want is:

```
select b.uniqueid, count(a.uniqueid) as num_a, b.cost
from b left join
     a
     on b.uniqueid = a.uniqueid
group by b.uniqueid, b.cost;
```

Optimizing a query depends a lot on the database.  For this query, an index on `a(uniqueid)` would definitely help.  And probably one on `b(uniqueid, b.cost)`.

Under some circumstances, it can be faster to write such a query as:

```
select b.uniqueid,
       (select count(*) from a where b.uniqueid = a.uniqueid) as num_a,
       b.cost
from b;
```

In this case, only the index on `a(uniqueid)` is really needed.

Answer (score 0):

If the join of this tables are your problem, maybe you can make a materialized views.
Other thing, you will need ask your self, are you really need all this data in this table in real time, ever? Maybe you can compress one part of this tables and make them more light.